# Formula to check for any instance of text string across Excel workbook?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of names in column A on a sheet in an Excel workbook. I want to check if any of those names matches an entry in column A of any other sheets in the workbook. The other sheets will be added to once a month (each is a summary of client data). So firstly if I can get a static formula that I have to extend each month manually that would do. But ideally I would prefer the check to work whenever I create a new sheet of data. I've tried this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(VSTACK(Sheet1:Sheet3!A:A)=A2))
```

but get a Num Error. Also I had to rename the sheets sheet1, sheet2 etc, and ideally I want to keep my sheet names e.g. Jan 2023, Feb 2023.

I already know how to use COUNTIF to check for instances on another sheet, but don't know how to extend that to cover all sheets.

Comment: Welcome! Are you sure you don't want to use a macro for this? It seems to me that [**this example**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.match#example) matches your description of the problem almost exactly.

Comment: do you want to know where the matches are (what sheet(s))?

Comment: I would rather not use a macro because eventually other users will be using what I am setting up and rely on the web version of Excel, which I think does not run VBA.
Knowing where the matches are would be a bonus, but just knowing how many exist would be enough.

Comment: For that you can consider Office Scripts (which do work on Excel Web) or using Google Sheets with App Scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that will list the matches.  You will need to manually add new ranges to the VSTACK formula. It compares a list of the UNIQUE values in the other sheets to `A:A` on the current sheet.  It doesn't compare `A:A` against itself for duplicates.

```
=LET(
   shts, VSTACK(
     UNIQUE('Feb 2023'!A:A),
     UNIQUE('Jan 2023'!A:A)),
   SORT(FILTER(shts,(shts<>"")*(COUNTIF(A:A,shts)))))
```

[image]  
[image]

[image]